# So, what's the best way to go about evaluating a device for class 1 div 2 ( or Zone 2)

Tags: embedded, certification

We purchase a small low power embedded computer from an OEM based out of United States. The device is not currently certified for Class 1 Div 2 (or Zone 2 which is the Canada/Euro equiv). We need this certification for use in Oil and Gas applications in Canada.

I suspect that the device itself would comply (it has no big caps and only consumes about 2.4 watts), and maybe only require a change in enclosure type. I don't want to throw money away before I have a decent understanding of what they will be looking for when doing a field certification (They being Intertek or CSA Labs).

So, what's the best way to go about evaluating the device for possible certification?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with explosion proof is that it's all in the enclosure. When I worked for an industrial power control company we would put our normal NEMA 1 rated equipment into massive steel enclosures with bolts every inch or two inches and it would meet all explosion proof requirements.

Crazy expensive enclosures, mind you, but the requirement is that if explosive vapours were present and a relay were to arc or a component fail and a spark be present, that it won't cause an explosion.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but being Class 1 div 2 compliant isn't quite the same as having an explosion proof rating...at least according to my limited understanding. I think I have seen solar packs rated class 1 div 2, but definitely not enclosed in explosion proof casings.